# Launching JNLP file from Linux

Tags: centos, java

There is a `.jnlp` file which can be launched from Windows. I now want to open it from Linux. The command is `javaws file.jnlp`. However, I get a segmentation fault and the verbose message is not meaningful.

```
mahmood@cluster:~$ javaws dynamic-jnlp-1463053293456.jnlp

(<unknown>:19075): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_notify: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Segmentation fault

mahmood@cluster:~$ javaws -verbose dynamic-jnlp-1463053293456.jnlp
Java(TM) Web Start 10.13.2.20-fcs Launching: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin/java
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin/java
-classpath
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/deploy.jar
-Djava.security.policy=file:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/security/javaws.policy
-DtrustProxy=true
-Xverify:remote
-Djnlpx.home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin
-Djnlpx.origFilenameArg=dynamic-jnlp-1463053293456.jnlp
-Djnlpx.remove=true
-Dsun.awt.warmup=true
-Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/lib/plugin.jar
-Xincgc
-Djnlp.localSeriesDownloader.className=gov.nih.nci.nbia.download.LocalSeriesDownloader
-Djnlp.remoteSeriesDownloader.className=gov.nih.nci.nbia.download.RemoteSeriesDownloader
-Djnlp.includeAnnotation=true
-Djnlp.userId=1234567
-Djnlp.password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-Djnlp.codebase=https://public.cancerimagingarchive.net/ncia
-Djnlp.downloadServerUrl=https://public.cancerimagingarchive.net/nbia-download/servlet/DownloadServlet
-Djnlp.noofretry=4
-Djnlpx.splashport=50515
-Djnlpx.jvm=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin/java
-Djnlpx.vmargs="-Xincgc     -Djnlp.localSeriesDownloader.className=gov.nih.nci.nbia.download.LocalSeriesDownloader   -Djnlp.remoteSeriesDownloader.className=gov.nih.nci.nbia.download.RemoteSeriesDownloader -Djnlp.includeAnnotation=true -Djnlp.userId=8950035    -Djnlp.password=4C61DF3B6DEF014345FC95ECD7434D118A4F47DFF1AA4C41E9EC3DEF36AC1E93 -Djnlp.codebase=https://public.cancerimagingarchive.net/ncia -Djnlp.downloadServerUrl=https://public.cancerimagingarchive.net/nbia-download/servlet/DownloadServlet -Djnlp.noofretry=4"
com.sun.javaws.Main
-verbose
-notWebJava
/tmp/javawqXVePj
```

What does that mean? Please note that `jdk1.7.0_13` is installed via yum.

There no not enough information about the error on the web.

**UPDATE**

I downloaded the [java-1.8](http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=207765) file (not the RPM) which contain the binary of `javaws`. Then I used the full path and it worked :)

```
/opt/jre1.8.0_91/bin/javaws file.jnlp
```

Comment: are you running the same java versions? by default the java that is shipped with CentOS is openjdk not the Oracle one, perhaps in Windows you will have the Oracle one.
I would start right there and ensure that the versions are the same vendor wise.

Comment: How can I find the version of the java embedded in the JNLP file?

Comment: Getting JNLP files to run is tricky, and often highly dependent on a Java version. I have got 3 Java versions installed in OS/X, the current one, the one need for the "new"  firewall 1.7, and the for the "old" firewall 1.6. When launching the file for the first time, you can specify the Java version, and then it outputs a directory/icon that I have to click every time.

Comment: @mahmood it is not the java embeded on jnlp .... it is the java vm on the OS. A quick look into google and you will find how to identify if you have oracle or openjava installed in your centos. After that, think a bit what shold be the next step. as I asked, did you compare the version of java vm used in Windows vs CentOS?

Comment: The solution has been added to the post

Comment: Comment from another [user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/249740/murray) with the same issue: The updated solution worked for me too - download and install JAVA_VERSION 1.8.0_91 - or whatever is the latest. Before that, I tried installing IcedTea Java Web Start - no luck, wouldn't parse/open/recognize my downloaded jnlp, and before that installed OpenJDK Java 8 Runtime - no luck opening it either. Works great now on Linux and the Java Web Start works just like it does on my Win 7 PC.

Comment: @mahmood, answers go in the Answer box, not as edits to the Question, please.